# ES6 JS tree shaking not working for antd lib

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, antd, tree-shaking

Tested it with `create-react-app@3.0.1` and JS tree shaking not working.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create new app `create-react-app treeshakeTest`
2. `cd treeshakeTest`
3. `npm i`
4. `npm i --save antd`
5. in `src/App.js` add `import Button from
   'antd/es/button'` at top and `<Button type="primary">Button</Button>`
   somewhere in the return

Result: with the `antd` import the bundle increases by `+171.28 KB` see image 
[image]

Prior to the `antd` import:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its seems it is a known issue with antd(icons are imported). V4 of the lib will fix this until then using https://github.com/Beven91/webpack-ant-icon-loader to split the icons chunk solved the issue.